# Back operation not working in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
driver.navigate().back();
```

Comment: You have to explain the problem a bit you know. Check out [ask] for help with editing your post.

Comment: A first guess is that you need to add waits there, after each click, to give the browser time to navigate to the following page, before going back to the original one?  Instead of using `sleep()`, you might want to wait for some elements that you know to be in the second page, but not the first one, to be visible/available...

Comment: Your button click happens without any error but intended action is not being triggered , yes ? That means it's not moving to back page also also no error, eh?

Comment: Why do you have this second time `driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();`

Answer (score 1):

If I right understand, after `click()` in your code snippet you are getting redirected to the another page and you want to go back. You can use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("your_url"));
driver.navigate().back();
```

you have to wait until you will be redirected to the new page and then go back.

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: Waiting for url doesn't tell you the fact that your page has loaded completely

Comment: @Rajagopalan It is not needed since OP wants to go back

Comment: What's the use of waiting for url here? To make sure `back`button loaded completely? Yes?

Comment: Lets say `A` is the previous url, `B` is current and `C` is next. If you won't wait until `C` url will be on the page(no need to load completely) with `back()` method you will be redirected to `A` and not to `B`

Comment: I understand but waiting for the url is not equivalent to waiting for button. He is saying his back button click is not working. There is a greater possibility that button click is being performed but intended action is not being triggered.

Comment: `He is saying his back button click is not working` - WHERE? He is saying `Back operation not working in selenium`. There is nothing about not working button click

Comment: Yes I do read that but he doesn't say it triggered any error at that line. So my guess selenium performs the click but application is not triggering the required action . I met such a situation many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this after loading of page is complete to go back to previous page  :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
```

Hope that helps you.